# Возвести произвольное число в произвольную степень, не используя цикл и спец функции?

Tags: python

как возвести произвольное число в произвольную степень, не используя цикл, pow и **? Прошу кратко, но доступно разъяснить

Comment: Использовать оператор `**`?

Comment: без оператора ** и без math.pow

Comment: ок.  а может, есть идеи, как это воплотить через функцию?

Answer (score 1):

можно с помощью рекурсии

```
def f(a, b):
    if b == 1:
        return a
    return a * f(a, b - 1)
```

Версия которая учитывает и возведение в нулевую степень и в отрицательую степень

```
def f(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    elif b == 1:
        return a
    elif b < 0:
        return 1 / f(a, -b)
    return a * f(a, b - 1)
```

Comment: Перед последней строкой можно ещё добавить b = int(b), чтобы дробные числа не ломали всё.

Answer (score 1):

школьная математика. `a^n = exp(ln(a)*n)`

```
import math
a = 2
n = 3
x = round(math.exp(math.log(a)*n))
print( x )
```

Comment: в каком классе такое проходят?

Comment: вроде как 10 класс. "свойства логарифмов"

Comment: спасибо! я только разбираюсь в python. новичок, как газ. не понял только, почему у вопроса рейтинг -4 сейчас